# React how to call function depends on specific element id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

how I can tigress an function depends on id of an element. Right now all elements getting clicked if I click on any single element. how to prevent to show all element ? here is my code

```
const[showsubcat,setShowSubCat] = useState(false)
   
   let subcategory=(()=>{
             
             setShowSubCat(prev=>!prev)
       })
```

**my jsx**

```
{data.map((data)=>{
                         return(
                          <>
                           
                          <li class="list-group-item" id={data.id}    onClick={subcategory} >{data.main_category}</li>
                            {showsubcat && 
                          <li><i class="las la-angle-right" id="sub_category"></i> {data.sub_category}</li>
                          }
                          
                          </>
                             

                         )
```

see the screenshot. I am clicking on single items but it's showing all items.

[image]

Comment: your update is not what i said

Comment: you missunderstood my answer that's not the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every li  should have it own state
so it's either you create states based on number of li if they're just 2  elements max! but it's ugly and when you want to add more li it's gonna be a mess
so you just create a component defining the ListItem and every component has it own state.

```
 function ListItem({data}) {
 const[showsubcat,setShowSubCat] = useState(false)

  const subcategory= ()=> setShowSubCat(prev=>!prev) 

 return (
         <>              
   <li class="list-group-item" id={data.id}    onClick={subcategory} > 
       {data.main_category}
   </li>
   {showsubcat && 
     <li>
        <i class="las la-angle-right" id="sub_category"></i> 
        {data.sub_category}
     </li>                     
    }
  </>
                      
)
}
```

and you use it in the list component like this

```
data.map((datum, index) => <ListItem key={index} data={datum} />
```

**EDIT AFTER THE POST UPDATE (misunderstanding)**

the list item (or the block containing the li and the helper text) should be an independant component to manage it own state

```
function PostAds(data) => {
  return ( 
   <>
   {
   data.map((data, index) => <ListItem key={index} data {data}/> 
   }
   </>
  )
}

function ListItem({data}) {
  const [showsubcat, setShowSubCat] = useState(false)

  const subcategory = () => setShowSubCat(prev => !prev)

  return (
       <>
      <li 
         class="list-group-item"
         id={data.id}
         onClick={subcategory}> 
         {data.main_category} 
      </li> 
      {
      showsubcat &&
      <li >
        <i  class = "las la-angle-right" id = "sub_category"></i>  
        {data.sub_category} 
      </li>                     
      }
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: not working I pass the argument index`<li class="list-group-item" id="category" key={index}    onClick={subcategory} >{data.main_category}</li>`

Comment: why you're passing the index to the li
inside the ListItem there is no index and no key

Comment: can you see my original question and let me know where to add in my code?

Comment: you should make the li block an independent component that manage it own states

Comment: you should create a ListItem componenet and  use it inside you main component where your List exists

Comment: let me know what exactly didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248378/discussion-between-boyenec-and-ismail-charfi).

Comment: Ismail Charfi working now. can you please tell me how can I make previous `showsubcat` status false when click on new category ? assume first I am click on category1 then If I click on subcategory2 then I want make subcategory status false

Comment: ok that makes the answer not valid anymore since the state is not independent per list item you should lift the state up and they should have shared state

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you are using the same variable `showsubcat` to check if the category was clicked or not.

A proper way to do this would be by either making `showsubcat` as an `array` that holds `id`s of those categories that were clicked like:

```
const[showsubcat,setShowSubCat] = useState([])
   
let subcategory=((categoryId)=> 
 showsubcat.includes(categoryId) ?  
   setShowSubCat(showsubcat.filter(el => el !== categoryId)) :  
   setShowSubCat([...showsubcat, categoryId]));
```

and then while mapping the data:

```
{data.map((category)=>
   (
      <>
         <li class="list-group-item" id={category.id} key={category.id}    
          onClick={() => subcategory(category.id)}>
            {category.main_category}
         </li>
        
         {showsubcat.includes(category.id) && 
                          <li>
                              <i class="las la-angle-right" 
                               id="sub_category" key={`subCategory${category.id}`} /> 
                              {category.sub_category} 
                          </li>
         }                        
      </>
  )
}
```

The other method would be to add a new key in your `data` array as `selectedCategory` and change its value to `true/false` based on the click, but this is a bit lengthy, let me know if you still want to know that process.

Also, accept the answer if it helps!

Comment: getting error `showsubcat.includes is not a function`

Comment: Have you declared `showsubcat` as `array`?